# Redirecting from path with query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to match this path

```
/news_entries?category_id=7
```

to redirect me here:

```
/categories/7/news_entries
```

This code doesn't work:

```
  match '/news_entries?category_id=:category_id' => redirect("/categories/%{category_id}/news_entries")
```

I tried to use constraints (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) but in this case I doesn't know how to put category_id parameter in match string.

Comment: how have u defined the route. if u specify the route neatly, u dont have to implement the above hack.

Comment: Resolved in controller
    `redirect_to news_entries_category_path(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id]`